# Setting the gradient colors from an arc

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint, linear-gradients

I am drawing an arc which shows the temperature variation.How can I set the gradient using the 3 colors (blue, green, red)? Using the below code.
 [I want to create an arc which looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmfHo.png).

```
mProgressPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(),new int[]{blue,green,red} ,new float[]{0,0.5F,1.0F},Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));   
canvas.drawArc(mArcRect, 0, 300, false, mProgressPaint);
```

For some reason, the colors are not distributed evenly. Need blue in the beginning, green in the middle and red at the end. How to assign positions to the colors properly in order to achieve the required gradient. Any link or sample code would be really helpful.

Comment: Like what? I tried different values and other combinations of the colors and still didn't work.

Comment: post the exact image of what you want to achieve - its worth more than 1024 words...

Comment: I have attached the link to the arc.

Comment: so you dont want `LinearGradient`, what you need is `SweepGradient` - search "google images" for `SweepGradient` to see it in action

Comment: yes I tried using `new SweepGradient(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2,new int[]{blue,green,red},null);` then also i got gradient with only blue and green color only.

Comment: google for `SweepGradient three colors` or similar and you will find a lot of code

Comment: I tried that, been stuck at this for days now. Couldn't find any proper solutions.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=SweepGradient+three+colors&oq=SweepGradient+three+colors

Comment: I will look into them again, thanks.

Comment: like this one: https://pastebin.com/raw/JGKP3gcu

Comment: I think I have an issue with the sweep angle. @pskink can we discuss this in a separate mail thread?

Comment: not 360 exactly. It's an arc and as the thumb is dragged the gradient should uniformly spread across the arc. So the angle will be from 0 to 300